# Convert MySQL database to SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, converters, dbmigrate

I have a MySQL database with some data and i want convert it to SQLite, please advise me any good tools(Windows) for it. I've tried SQLite Data Wizard, but it can't find already installed MySQL ODBC driver.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MikeW i already have described my problem - for this operation i'v used a SQLLite Data Wizard, but when i've tried to configure the connection, it can't see MYSQL ODBC Driver, it offered only MSSQL drivers, and even i've reinstalled MySQL ODBC Drivers it still found nothing.

Comment: How many tables in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only 15 tables I'd suggest the most straitforward way

1. just dump your MySQL tables using mysqldump
2. use a good text editor to edit your files to adjust data types in table definitions and potentially data values (find & replace)
3. use your sql script files to populate sqlite db

Comment: is it a best existing solution?

Comment: Do you see any better..?